# Jquery Ajax call to set variables doesn't persist outside of call

Tags: php, jquery, json

Not entirely sure why this is going wrong. Jquery Novice. It should work, according to all the examples I've seen, but it doesn't.

In the following script, the function sets new values for variables, but the new values don't persist outside the function. (console logs show this)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // url
    var path = location.pathname.split("/"),
        pos1_path = path[1] != undefined ? path[1] : false,
        pos2_path = path[2] != undefined ? path[2] : false,
        pos3_path = path[3] != undefined ? path[3] :  false;

    //console.log('before: ' + pos2_path);
    if (pos1_path = 'article') {
        $.post("/js/ajax/article_crumbs.php", { func: "getArticleCrumbs" },
            function(data){
                pos2_path = data.category;
                //console.log('during: ' + pos2_path);
            return pos2_path}, "json");
    }
    //console.log('after: ' + pos2_path);

    // navigation
    // set category nav to current category
    if ( path[2] ) {
        $('#category_nav a[class$="' + pos2_path + '"]').toggleClass('current');
    }
    else {
        $('#category_nav a:first').toggleClass('current');
    }
});
```

The PHP:

```
<?php echo json_encode(["category"=>"arts-and-culture"]);
```

Also, according to the console printouts, the "after" print out appears before the "during", does that mean the function doesn't run until the end of the rest of the script?

**EDIT:** To clarify, I need to keep the **{ if(path[1]) *setcurrent*  }** part of the script out of the **{ if(pos1_path = 'article') }** part so that if pos1_path is NOT article, it sets the value to whatever is in the URI..

**SOLUTION** as per answer below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // url
    var path = location.pathname.split("/"),
        pos1_path = path[1] != undefined ? path[1] : false,
        pos2_path = path[2] != undefined ? path[2] : false,
        pos3_path = path[3] != undefined ? path[3] :  false;

    if (pos1_path = 'article') {
        //console.log('before: ' + pos2_path);
        var data = {id: pos2_path}
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "/js/ajax/article_crumbs.php",
            data: data,
            success: function(data){
                pos2_path = data.category;
                //console.log('during: ' + pos2_path);},
            dataType: "json",
            async: false
        });
    }
    //console.log('after: ' + pos2_path);

    // navigation
    // set category nav to current category
    if ( path[2] ) {
        $('#category_nav a[class$="' + pos2_path + '"]').toggleClass('current');
    }
    else {
        $('#category_nav a:first').toggleClass('current');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$.post request is asynchronous call so obviously it will move on to rest of the lines of code and not wait for callback of $.post

Try using `$.ajax` instead and make it `async=false` to use same code

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType,
  async:false
});
```

OR

Move your code inside success callback.

Comment: Perfect. works. I updated my post with the new script. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // url
    var path = location.pathname.split("/"),
        pos1_path = path[1] != undefined ? path[1] : false,
        pos2_path = path[2] != undefined ? path[2] : false,
        pos3_path = path[3] != undefined ? path[3] :  false;

    if (pos1_path = 'article') {
        var data = {id: pos2_path}
        $.post("/js/ajax/article_crumbs.php", { func: "getArticleCrumbs" },
            function(data){
                pos2_path = data.category;
                // navigation
                // set category nav to current category
                if ( path[1] ) {
                    $('#category_nav a[class$="' + pos2_path + '"]').toggleClass('current');
                }
                else {
                    $('#category_nav a:first').toggleClass('current');
                }
            }, "json");
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks, but can't do that. I need to keep the { if(path[1]) setcurrent  } part of the script out of the { if(pos1_path = 'article') } part so that if pas1_path is NOT article, it sets the value to whatever is in the URI.. but thanks though..

Answer (score 0):

This is an asynchronous call... So when control reaches `if ( path[2] ) {` statement, you can not assure whether server has responded or not...

You can do your operations in the `success callback` of `$.post`

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // url
    var path = location.pathname.split("/"),
        pos1_path = path[1] != undefined ? path[1] : false,
        pos2_path = path[2] != undefined ? path[2] : false,
        pos3_path = path[3] != undefined ? path[3] :  false;

    //console.log('before: ' + pos2_path);
    if (pos1_path = 'article') {
        $.post("/js/ajax/article_crumbs.php", { func: "getArticleCrumbs" },
            function(data){
                pos2_path = data.category;
                if ( path[2] ) {
                    $('#category_nav a[class$="' + pos2_path +'"]').toggleClass('current');
                } else {
                    $('#category_nav a:first').toggleClass('current');
                }
            },"json")
    }
})
```

Comment: Please check OP for explanation why i can't do it this way. Thanks though.